# fullcalendar-4 inside a function

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

The fullcalendar 4.3.1 will not initialize when called within a function.

The selectable.html example present the calendar perfectly, but when I put the code into a function and call the function from the , it no longer displays the calendar.

I have pasted in the abridged selectable.html that I tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='../packages/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../packages/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../packages/timegrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='../packages/core/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/interaction/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/daygrid/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/timegrid/main.js'></script>
<script>


function OpenProgram()
{
    StartCalendar();
}

function StartCalendar()
{  
debugger;
       //document.getElementById("calendar").style.visibility = "visible"; 
       DrawCalendar1();
      //bottomButtons(); 
}

function DrawCalendar1()
{
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      defaultDate: '2019-08-12',
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      selectable: true,
      selectMirror: true,
      select: function(arg) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        if (title) {
          calendar.addEvent({
            title: title,
            start: arg.start,
            end: arg.end,
            allDay: arg.allDay
          })
        }
        calendar.unselect()
      },
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: [
        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2019-08-01'
        },
        {
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: '2019-08-07',
          end: '2019-08-10'
        },
        {
          groupId: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2019-08-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          groupId: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2019-08-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Conference',
          start: '2019-08-11',
          end: '2019-08-13'
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2019-08-12T10:30:00',
          end: '2019-08-12T12:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Lunch',
          start: '2019-08-12T12:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2019-08-12T14:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Happy Hour',
          start: '2019-08-12T17:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Dinner',
          start: '2019-08-12T20:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Birthday Party',
          start: '2019-08-13T07:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Click for Google',
          url: 'http://google.com/',
          start: '2019-08-28'
        }
      ]
    });

    calendar.render();
  });
}

</script>
<style>

  body {
    margin: 40px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  #calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body onload="OpenProgram()">

  <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I debug, there are no errors with the code.

How do I get the calendar to display when calling it from inside a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `onload` and also `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'` at the same time really makes no sense - they both do a very similar job, i.e. making the code wait until the page has loaded before being executed.

However, by the time you run `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'`, the `DOMContentLoaded` event has already happened, so the assigned callback never fires - which is why the calendar never loads.

Rather than using an inline `onload`, which is generally considered a rather old-fashioned (and less maintainable, due to having inline JS inside the HTML) way to do it, a sensible approach would be to handle `DOMContentLoaded` outside any function (so the handler is added immediately as the script block is loaded) and then call your `OpenProgram` function within it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='../packages/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../packages/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../packages/timegrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='../packages/core/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/interaction/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/daygrid/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/timegrid/main.js'></script>    

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', OpenProgram);

function OpenProgram()
{
    StartCalendar();
}

function StartCalendar()
{  
console.log("here");
       //document.getElementById("calendar").style.visibility = "visible"; 
       DrawCalendar1();
      //bottomButtons(); 
}

function DrawCalendar1()
{
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      defaultDate: '2019-08-12',
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      selectable: true,
      selectMirror: true,
      select: function(arg) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        if (title) {
          calendar.addEvent({
            title: title,
            start: arg.start,
            end: arg.end,
            allDay: arg.allDay
          })
        }
        calendar.unselect()
      },
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: [
        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2019-08-01'
        },
        {
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: '2019-08-07',
          end: '2019-08-10'
        },
        {
          groupId: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2019-08-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          groupId: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2019-08-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Conference',
          start: '2019-08-11',
          end: '2019-08-13'
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2019-08-12T10:30:00',
          end: '2019-08-12T12:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Lunch',
          start: '2019-08-12T12:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2019-08-12T14:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Happy Hour',
          start: '2019-08-12T17:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Dinner',
          start: '2019-08-12T20:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Birthday Party',
          start: '2019-08-13T07:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Click for Google',
          url: 'http://google.com/',
          start: '2019-08-28'
        }
      ]
    });

    calendar.render();
}
</script>
<style>

  body {
    margin: 40px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  #calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/YzKQqdr